# zurb ink email wrapper doesnt span across full width

Tags: html-email, zurb-ink

I'm having issues with Zurb Ink's email. So it looks fine in desktop, however it there is this gap when it hits the media queries and it seems to be doing it with the containers when its stacked on top of each other. I want it to span the whole width.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xygNK.png

Here is my code:

```
<table class="container" id="hero-container">
        <!-- hero logo -->
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table class="row">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="wrapper last">
                            <table class="twelve columns">
                                <tr>
                                    <td id="hero-logo"><img id="logoImage" src="images/hero-logo.png" alt="Hero In The News" /></td>
                                    <td class="expander"></td>
                                </tr>           
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- /hero logo -->
        <!-- hero image -->
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table class="row">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="wrapper last">
                            <table class="twelve columns">
                                <tr>
                                    <td><img id="headerImage" src="images/hero-img.png" alt="City of San Jose - Capital of Silicon Valley" /></td>
                                    <td class="expander"></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- /hero image -->
        <!-- hero main article -->
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table class="row">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="wrapper last">
                                <table class="twelve columns">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="heading1 text-pad">Residents can Pace Energy Use <br/>with New Program</td>
                                        <td class="expander"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <table class="row">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="wrapper last">
                                <table class="twelve columns">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="text-pad"><p>The city of San Jose has implemented a program to help residents pace their water and energy consumption. </p></td>
                                        <td class="expander"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <!-- button -->
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table class="row">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="wrapper last">
                                <table class="twelve columns">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="text-pad link"><p><a href="http://www.mercurynews.com/san-jose-neighborhoods/ci_25900245/residents-can-pace-energy-use-new-program">Read Full Article</a></p></td>
                                        <td class="expander"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <!--/button --> 
        <!-- /hero main article -->
      </table>    



      <!--  articles row 1 -->
      <table class="container">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table class="row">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="wrapper">
                            <table class="six columns article">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="text-pad">
                                        <h2>Energy Efficiency Program Ushers Green Jobs into Kern</h2>
                                        <p>The green economy has arrived in Kern County, and not a moment...</p>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="expander"></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                        <td class="wrapper last">
                            <table class="six columns article">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="text-pad">
                                        <h2>Stockton Gets a New “HERO”</h2>
                                        <p>From insulation to more efficient air conditioning to solar panels to...</p>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="expander"></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <!-- /articles row 1-->

      <!--  articles row 2 -->
      <table class="container article-container">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table class="row">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="wrapper article-wrapper">
                            <table class="six columns article">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="text-pad">
                                        <h2>Fresno estimates $56M from HERO program</h2>
                                        <p>Officials with the City of Fresno expect to see more than $56 M...</p>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="expander"></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                        <td class="wrapper last article-wrapper-last">
                            <table class="six columns article">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="text-pad">
                                        <h2>Lompoc City Council approves HERO Program</h2>
                                        <p>A new program that helps homeowners make energy and...</p>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="expander"></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
```

Comment: It seems to be that its doing that because I don't have enough content.. but not sure how to remedy it except for cheat a little and try to add &nbsp;

Comment: There seems to definitely be a problem.  Trying the provided sidebar template works fine with a link tag in the header (browser), but when the css gets inlined the width becomes unresponsive (mail & browser). see gif: [here](http://i751.photobucket.com/albums/xx155/willko747/InkUnresponsiveWidth_zpsu3wnbcoo.gif)

Answer (score 0):

Caveat:  I am new to Ink myself.  What "jumps out" at me is that you're using a container on the outside and multiple rows inside.  For full width, swap the row and container classes --> so that the table with class row contains a table with class container.